# A Swift Definition of Time

Tags: swift

With respect to the source code for the `Measurement` and `UnitDuration` classes; where can I find the definition that there are sixty seconds in a minute?  The nearest I have found is the code below:

```
open class UnitDuration : Dimension, NSSecureCoding {

    @NSCopying open class var hours: UnitDuration { get }

    @NSCopying open class var minutes: UnitDuration { get }

    @NSCopying open class var seconds: UnitDuration { get }

    etc.    
}
```

Comment: Interesting question!  The closest I've come is the `NSCalendar.Unit` struct in Foundation  that provides all the time/date constants, but these are just the constants.  I can never remember if Foundation is open-sourced or not, but if it is you could always go tot he source code.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Unit.swift#L635

Comment: @MartinR Perfect!  Thank (again) Martin (and flanker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[swift-corelibs-foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation) is the (open source) implementation of (essential parts) of the Foundation library for non-Apple platforms.

What you are looking for is in [Unit.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Unit.swift#L635):

```
private struct Coefficient {
    static let seconds  = 1.0
    static let minutes  = 60.0
    static let hours    = 3600.0
}

private convenience init(symbol: String, coefficient: Double) {
    self.init(symbol: symbol, converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: coefficient))
}

public class var seconds: UnitDuration {
    get {
        return UnitDuration(symbol: Symbol.seconds, coefficient: Coefficient.seconds)
    }
}

public class var minutes: UnitDuration {
    get {
        return UnitDuration(symbol: Symbol.minutes, coefficient: Coefficient.minutes)
    }
}

public class var hours: UnitDuration {
    get {
        return UnitDuration(symbol: Symbol.hours, coefficient: Coefficient.hours)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from Apple docs

> Declaration
>
> class UnitDuration : Dimension
>
> Overview
>
> You typically use instances of NSUnitDuration to represent
>   specific quantities of planar angle using the NSMeasurement class.
>
> Duration Duration is a quantity of time. The SI unit for time is the
>   second (sec), which is defined in terms of the radioactivity of a
>   cesium-133 atom. Duration is also commonly expressed in terms of
>   minutes (min) and hours (hr).
>
> Note
>
> Use the NSDateComponents class to represent quantities of calendrical
>   units, such as days, weeks, months, and years. The NSUnitDuration
>   class defines its base unit as seconds, and provides the following
>   units, which are initialized using UnitConverterLinear converters with
>   the specified coefficients:

```
Name    Method  Symbol Coefficient 
Seconds seconds sec    1 
Minutes minutes min    60 
Hours   hours   hr     3600
```

In reality, the symbol for Seconds is different :-)

```
UnitDuration.seconds.symbol // "s"
UnitDuration.minutes.symbol // "min"
UnitDuration.hours.symbol   // "hr"
```

and coefficients are, as expected

```
UnitDuration.minutes.converter.baseUnitValue(fromValue: 1.0)    // 60
UnitDuration.minutes.converter.value(fromBaseUnitValue: 60.0)   // 1
UnitDuration.hours.converter.baseUnitValue(fromValue: 1.0)      // 3600
UnitDuration.hours.converter.value(fromBaseUnitValue: 3600.0)   // 1
```

What about angles? Are values usable? **I don't think so ...**

```
UnitAngle.baseUnit().symbol                                     // "°"
UnitAngle.degrees.converter.value(fromBaseUnitValue: 1.0)       // 1

UnitAngle.arcSeconds.converter.baseUnitValue(fromValue: 3600.0) // 1.000008
UnitAngle.arcMinutes.converter.value(fromBaseUnitValue: 1.0)    // 59.99880002399951
UnitAngle.arcMinutes.converter.baseUnitValue(fromValue: 60.0)   // 1.00002
UnitAngle.arcSeconds.converter.value(fromBaseUnitValue: 1.0)    // 3599.971200230398
```